# Find function tracing the maximum of a 2D function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I'd like to solve the following problem: Given

```
MI[o_, n_] := Log2[1 + 4 o (Sqrt@n + Sqrt[1 + n])^2]
```

Find a function `f[n_]` that tells which `o` to use to optimise (maximise) `MI`.

My first pen and paper approach was to calculate the gradient of the function. Then, starting from the origin, the idea is to step "a little bit" into this direction to get to the next, best, point. However, for a closed solution, this means solving an iteration problem. So I went to Mathematica. Here, the approach looks like

```
Maximize[{MI[o, n], 0 <= Sqrt[o^2 + n^2] <= b, b > 0}, {o, n}]
```

This is out of Mathematica's (10.2) power. What works at least is

```
a = 3;
Simplify@Maximize[{MI[o, n], 0 <= Sqrt[o^2 + n^2] <= a}, {o, n}]
```

If someone has an idea of an approach that leads to a symbolic solution, I'd be happy!

PS: As @march, @rhermans and @Jack LaVigne pointed out, the question only makes sense when using a bound to `o` and `n`, which I did not mention (besides implicitly in the last code).

Comment: What makes you believe your expression does have a maximum?

Comment: You have a constraint on `o` and `n` in your `Maximize` function. Are you maximizing `MI` subject to this constraint? Because otherwise, as @rhermans notes, it seems like your function grows monotonically with both `o` and `n`.

Comment: If constrained to a disk you could use `Maximize[mi[o, n], {o, n} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, a], Reals]` but apparently there is no simple general form for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a plot of your function over a region you will see that it grows to infinity as `o` and `n` increase.

```
mi[o_, n_] := Log2[1 + 4 o (Sqrt@n + Sqrt[1 + n])^2]

Plot3D[mi[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it is certain that you need to place a bound on it.

Let's plot your example with a radius of three or less.

```
max = Maximize[{mi[o, n], 0 <= Sqrt[o^2 + n^2] <= 3}, {o, n}]
```

outputs an expression containing `Root`. We can get the numerical value from:

```
N[max]
(* {6.48452, {o -> 2.2254, n -> 2.01186}} *)
```

and we can plot the function, a cylinder with radius of three and the solution as a red point.

```
Show[
 Plot3D[mi[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic] /. 
  EdgeForm[] -> Sequence[EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.4]],
 ParametricPlot3D[{3 Cos[theta], 3 Sin[theta], z}, {theta, 0, 
   90 Degree}, {z, 0, max[[1]]}],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red,
   PointSize -> 0.04,
   Point[{o, n, max[[1]]} /. N[max[[2]]]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From this plot it is clear that the solution will lie on the boundary defined by the constraint.

We can use that fact to eliminate one variable.

We will replace `o` with `Sqrt[b^2 - n^2]` (tip from ***Clemens***)

When we make a plot of `mi[o,Sqrt[b^2 - n^2]]` and observe that it has a similar shape (more or less) independent of the parameter `b`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[mi[Sqrt[b^2 - n^2], n], {n, 0, b}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}],
 {{b, 2}, 0.5, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now the strategy is to locate where the derivative is zero.

```
sol = Solve[D[mi[Sqrt[b^2 - n^2], n], n] == 0 && b > 0, n, Reals]
```

results in

```
{{n -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-b^4 + 2 b^2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
    0 < b < (3 Sqrt[3/2])/4]},
 {n -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-b^4 + 2 b^2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
    b > (3 Sqrt[3/2])/4]}}
```

So for example if you want to find the value at `b=2` you can use:

```
n /. sol /. b -> 2.
(* {Undefined, 1.31088} *)
```

**Analyze the solution**

The solution uses the same `Root` function but the first and third roots depending upon the value of `b`.

Let's plot `n` as a function of the radius `b`.

```
f1[b_] := Root[-b^4 + 2 b^2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]

f3[b_] := Root[-b^4 + 2 b^2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]

Show[
 Plot[f1[b], {b, 0.001, (3 Sqrt[3/2])/4}, PlotStyle -> Blue,
    AxesLabel -> {b, n}],
 Plot[f3[b], {b, (3 Sqrt[3/2])/4, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2.1}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`n` is a nice smooth curve as a function of `b`.

**Function**

Last step is to create a function which outputs `o`, `n`, `mi` as a function of `b`.

```
parametricFun[b_] := Module[
  {
   o,
   n,
   z
   },
  n = If[b < (3 Sqrt[3/2])/4,
    Root[-b^4 + 2 b^2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1],
    Root[-b^4 + 2 b^2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]
    ];
  o = Sqrt[b^2 - n^2];
  z = mi[o, n];
  {o, n, z}
  ]
```

Now plot the maximum `mi` as a function of `b`.

```
Show[
 Plot3D[mi[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic] /.
  EdgeForm[] -> Sequence[EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.4]],

 (ParametricPlot3D[{# Cos[theta], # Sin[theta], z},
      {theta, 0, 90 Degree}, {z, 0, parametricFun[#][[3]]},
      Mesh -> None] /.
     EdgeForm[] -> Sequence[EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.6]])
   & /@ Range[1, 7],

 ParametricPlot3D[parametricFun[b], {b, 0, 7}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}],

 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize -> 0.025,
   Point[parametricFun[#] & /@ Range[7]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: note that `ToRadicals[
 Root[-b^6 + 
    b^8 + (3 b^4 - 4 b^6) #1^2 + (-3 b^2 + 4 b^4) #1^4 + #1^6 &, 1]]` give a "closed form" expression. (Not a nice one...)

Comment: Solving for `n` instead of `o` makes the expressions much nicer. It also prevents from the problem encountered at `b == 1` in `o /. sol /. b -> 1.`.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the observation. I have completed the answer by creating the function and incorporated your tip.